# Please ignore the test event

Tags: discussion, support

Well, while testing a feature I knew was there, I accidentally added an event that won't go away.

If you see an event on the sidebar called "Test" - and are wondering, this was *entirely* my fault, and I'll probably poke someone about removing it once I'm over the embarrassment.

I've taken the opportunity to add an easier to find link to the chatroom, just to see if it'll help people find it though.